# Can Spring Batch use no-sql database to store batch metadata?

Tags: nosql, spring-batch

Can Spring Batch use no-sql database (e.g. firestore, mongodb, etc.) to store batch metadata? If yes, can you share sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can, but it does not provide an implementation yet. We have a feature request for that here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/877.

That said, it is a matter of implementing a single interface: `JobRepository`. Otherwise, you can implement the 4 DAOs required by Spring Batch using your NoSQL database (`JobInstanceDao`, `JobExecutionDao`, `StepExecutionDao`, `ExecutionContextDao`) and use them with the provided `SimpleJobRepository`.