# How to use a cacheing layer in Spring Batch instead of H2

Tags: spring, redis, spring-batch, hazelcast

I am curious to know if anyone has been able to successfully use a cache such Hazelcast or Redis with spring batch as the persistence layer instead of a full RDMS.

The reason I am asking such a question is I would like to measure the performance of my application without the latency induced from transacting when many parallel steps are processing as well as when there is a high amount of threads processing in a multi-threaded step.

My current thoughts on this is that it is possible as we can use the DataSource configuration with a JobRepository.

If this is not possible is there a way to do the step level transactions on the persistence layer(PostgreSQL for example) asynchronously to avoid the seconds delay in a step starting and ending.

Thank you if any code snippet is needed I will be more than happy to share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any persistence technology you want for the job repository, as long as your implementation respects the `JobRepository` contract.

Now if the requirement is to measure the performance of your job under particular conditions, I would not change the persistence layer just for that. I would rather recommend to profile the execution with the **same** job repository in a staging environment that is as close as possible to your production environment. Any decent profiler would give you the performance details of your step and the overhead of transactions.

Comment: Understood thank you I have a brief follow up question:
Is there anyway to change when steps transact on the Persistence layer? From this post [NoSQL Support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75459069/can-spring-batch-use-no-sql-database-to-store-batch-metadata/75469862#75469862) 
I believe I could change when steps transact on the DB by altering the StepExecutionDao. 
The reason I am asking such questions is in my production environment I observed that when I use 32 concurrent steps, where each step has 32 parallel threads processing it there large delay from a step starting to ending.

Comment: `Is there anyway to change when steps transact on the Persistence layer?`: change what?

Comment: I apologize for any confusion. To clarify my previous comment, I am wondering if re-implementing StepExecutionDao and other Dao classes found in the NoSQL Support link would affect when steps commit to the database. Specifically, I am trying to modify how steps commit transactions because Spring Batch's default behaviour includes multi-threaded steps and parallel steps execute transactions at the beginning and end of each step. This can result in performance degradation when using multiple levels of threading as there is blocking due to the hikari pool not having enough of connections.

Comment: No, providing custom DAOs does not impact the main step implementation that drives the flow and controls transaction boundaries. What you seem to try to do requires a custom `Step` implementation, not custom DAOs implementations. Again, I don't think this is required just to measure the performance.

Comment: Well my goal at the moment is to understand the performance of my application. I have used JProfiler and can physically see that the slowest part of my Job right now is the I/O to the remote DB at the start and end of individual steps. What I wanted to try doing is running a local cache instead of a remote RDBMS to then compare the results between the two. My obvious expectation is that caching will be dramatically faster. Do you have any thoughts as to how I can do this?

Comment: There is nothing to cache. Caching is used to optimize reads. At step boundaries, steps *write* metadata to the repository for later use in case of failure if any. This part cannot be optimized by using a cache. What you can do is use an in-memory database for the job repository, which should be fast enough as there is no disk I/O.